# Workflow 2013 throws an error on start in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

it showing error  "Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to http://xxxxxxxxxx/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail Correlation Id: 025fdd3c-b97d-4b85-90bb-939a705a4c7a Instance Id: e448df02-9086-4c7e-97f1-ca293f687689"

Comment: did you put a valid email address in the Recipient/CC/BCC? Also do you have any variables that don't have any values?

Comment: I am selecting  email address from user and group field.

Comment: have you followed the correlationid to see what the ULS Logs say?